# Application/JSON is Unsupported Media Type in restful webservice

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I am trying to create a restful-jersey webservice. I have to pass JSON object to the webservice.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/saveVehicleTrackingData")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String saveVehicleTrackingData(VehicleTracking vehicleTracking) {
        return vehicleTracking.toString();
    }
```

When I try try to make request to the service, it says **HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type.** Please help. Also, what should be the type of single argument of the method **saveVehicleTrackingData**.

PS: I am using POSTMAN to make http request. http://goo.gl/vwXNXQ

[image]

**UPDATE :**
As pointed out by peeskillet, the missing thing here is JSON Provider. The next challenge that I have is, how to integrate the JSON Provider in my project. After researching a little, I found **FasterXML jackson** as one of the JSON provider.

Comment: How are you making the request? Are you specifying the content type as application/json?

Comment: Agreed, it most likely is you are not sending in your request as JSON content type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

This image is just for reference. I just had it from another post.

Basically when you use <kbd>raw</kbd>, it will default to `text/plain`. The <kbd>JSON</kbd> in the drop down, is simply to select syntax highlighting. You still need to set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. You can click on the <kbd>Headers</kbd> button and add it.

Comment: Unfortunately, setting the header didn't work(although it may be necessary). Problem is not with the postman request (As I did similar type of experiment with text/plain media type), it's with the **type of single agrument** that is being passed to the method **saveVehicleTrackingData**. What should the proper type?

Comment: Post the whole stacktrace. It should be logged

Comment: As for the type, it could be any type that can be parse into by the reader provider. Do you even have a JSON provider?

Comment: And doing a test with `text/plain` means nothing, if the method argument is still an object type. `text/plain` is simple a string. How does the reader know how to convert a string to your POJO? You need to make sure you have a JSON provider as a dependency and configured.

Comment: JSON Provider is a new thing to me. Hope that will help. I am trying to use FasterXML jackson json provider. I have added the required maven dependency in my POM(<groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>,<artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>). Can you please help me further how to configure my project, so that JSON data may get automatically converted to POJO whenever a request is made to the webservice.

Comment: What Jersey version are you using? Show your web.xml or ResourceConfig. Update you post, don't put in in comments

Answer (score 0):

**For your first question:**

What kind of hosting (Tomcat, GlassFish or whatever...) are you using, and what is the Java version of the host? I know from experience that different version of Tomcat in combination with Jersey sometimes gives problems with `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)`.

**About your second question:**

You want to build a RESTful webservice, the right name for a path should be; *VehicleTrackingData* (or whatever you like). This path will work (request/response) with the known HTTP verbs; GET, POST, PUT or DELETE.

Comment: Just as a side note, GET/DELETE should never be passed a request body.